# pathForResources returning (null)

Tags: path, null, nsstring, bundle, nslog

I am using these lines of code

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"test"];
 NSLog(@"%@", path);
```

And the NSLog is printing out (null).

The file I'm trying to read is index.html. It is in the test folder which is in my project folder. Does anyone know why path returns (null).

Thanks

Clinton

Answer (score 0):

This method will return nil if your resource can't be found. Try another one like `-(NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath` specifying 'test' as the directory name.

Also make sure your file is included into your app bundle...